# Initialize Facebook like button post page load and script execution

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook-like

So I have a [like button](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Like_button) on my page which loads fine when the script is executed in the bottom of the page. The problem is that I have an Ajax based popout which renders some HTML that also has the like button. How can I initialize that?

I've tried putting same script, but it doesn't get executed.

Is there a way to explicitly call any method to initialize the button?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`FB.XFBML.parse()` will do the trick